# How to filter dataframe rows if column value (string) contains any of the values in a set in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter rows if cell string contains anyone of the values in the predefined set.

For example, for following dataframe:

```
   ids ids2  vals
0  a h  a i     1
1  b z  n a     2
2  f z  c a     3
3  n i  n h     4
```

I want following rows extracted (the rows which have 'h' or 'i' in the ids column):

```
   ids ids2  vals
0  a h  a i     1
3  n i  n h     4
```

Code to generate dataframe:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ids': ['a h', 'b z', 'f z', 'n i'],'ids2': ['a i', 'n a', 'c a', 'n h']})
```

What I have done so far:

```
d[d['ids'].str.contains('h')|d['ids'].str.contains('i')]
```

Here the predefined set is small and contains is case sensitive. Is there a way I can do this either with case-insensitivity or using some list contains method. I tried doing this:

```
d[len(re.findall('h|i',d['ids'].str,re.IGNORECASE)) > 0]
```

but it gives me `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`.

or this:

```
data[any(d['name'].str.contains(x) for x in ['h','i'])]
```

gives error: `KeyError: 'name'`
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case = False` to make it case-insensitive:

`d[d['ids'].str.contains('h', case=False)|d['ids'].str.contains('i',case=False)]`

This is definitely a little roundabout but it will work:

```
letters = ['h', 'i']
d[d['ids'].str.split().apply(lambda x: len(set(x).intersection(set(letters))))>0]
```

Comment: Ok. Even then I will have to write a lot of `or` statements for a bigger list

Comment: @harshit the current solution will work as long as you specify all possible letters in `letters`

Comment: Why declare letters as a list only to convert it to set?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by passing a regex that joins the terms:

```
In [132]:
d[~d['ids'].str.contains('h|i', case=False)]

Out[132]:
   ids ids2  vals
1  b z  n a     2
2  f z  c a     3
```