# How to select the rows where last column of dataframe contains specific value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

```
Duration Protocol Direction Label
12        tcp     bi        normal-V45
2         udp     one       Botnet-45
2         icmp    bi        Botnet-68
3         tcp     one       normal-V73
5         udp     bi        Background-tcp
3         icmp    one       Background
```

I want to select the rows that have last column(label) as either normal or Botnet.
I have to check the condition if Label contains normal/Botnet , (here normal-V45 and normal-V73 are considered normal, similar concept for botnet). So output should be:

```
Duration Protocol Direction Label
12        tcp     bi        normal-V45
2         udp     one       Botnet-45
2         icmp    bi        Botnet-68
3         tcp     one       normal-V73
```

I use the following in pandas, but all the data comes in csv. Help appreciated.Waiting. Thanks a lot in advance: data1 is the dataframe where all data is, [~data1.iloc[:,-1].str is for selecting last column.

`datagrouped = data1.loc[~data1.iloc[:,-1].str == 'Botnet']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter dataframe rows if column value (string) contains any of the values in a set in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167381/how-to-filter-dataframe-rows-if-column-value-string-contains-any-of-the-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.str.contans` with regex and boolean indexing:

```
df[df.Label.str.contains(r'normal|Botnet')]
```

Output:

```
   Duration Protocol Direction       Label
0        12      tcp        bi  normal-V45
1         2      udp       one   Botnet-45
2         2     icmp        bi   Botnet-68
3         3      tcp       one  normal-V73
```

Comment: I did not know about that feature. As [the manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) shows, per default it is a regular expression (re module) match, so you can even be more specific, like `df[df.Label.str.contains(r'^(normal|Botnet)\-')]`. Or you can use python without regex and combine it yourself with the boolean operators like `df[df.Label.str.contains('normal', regex=False) | df.Label.str.contains('Botnet', regex=False)]`. In this case I guess the first is to be preferred.